# Ruby blocks example not working as it is supposed to

Tags: ruby, scope

I have just started learning ruby reading from different resources. One of them is rubylearning.com, and I was just reading the [blocks section](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html) and doing the exercises. For some reason, this example's scope is working differently in my case:

```
x = 10  
5.times do |x|  
  puts "x inside the block: #{x}"  
end  

puts "x outside the block: #{x}"
```

The output should be ( according to the site):

```
x inside the block: 0  
x inside the block: 1  
x inside the block: 2  
x inside the block: 3  
x inside the block: 4  
x outside the block: 10
```

But my output is:

```
x inside the block: 0
x inside the block: 1
x inside the block: 2
x inside the block: 3
x inside the block: 4
x outside the block: 4
```

Any idea why? This section is supposed to be about the scope in ruby blocks, but I am totally confused now...

EDIT:

Ok I just realized something: I was executing my code from textmate. If i run it from the command line i get the expected result, plus 1.9.2 RUBY_VERSION. But I get 1.8.7 running it from Textmate. Has textmate its own version of ruby installed or something? – 0al0 0 secs ago edit

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.2, according to ruby -v

Comment: are you *sure* about that? With Ruby 1.9.2 you should be getting the first (expected) result. (Ruby 1.8.x would output the second version)

Comment: try "puts RUBY_VERSION" in your script

Comment: @levinalex I did what you said and I got 1.8.7. But i do get 1.9.2 using ruby -v...

Comment: Ok I just realized something: I was executing my code from textmate. If i run it from the command line i get the expected result, plus 1.9.2 RUBY_VERSION. But I get 1.8.7 running it from Textmate. Has textmate its own version of ruby installed or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example works since ruby 1.9.1 as the article explain:

> In Ruby 1.9.1, blocks introduce their
>   own scope for the block parameters
>   only.

So you are working with another ruby version, try this:

```
ruby -v
```

I recommend to install [rvm](https://rvm.io) to manage different ruby versions.

Answer (score 4):

You are using an outdated version of Ruby. The scope of block local variables has changed in Ruby 1.9.0+.